# How to change one property value in array with objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have const tab where I want to change property isActive from boolean to 'on' or 'off' depending on if it's true or false.

```
   const tab = [
   {id:'0',original:{lineId:'4', isActive:false, length: '3'}},
   {id:'1',original:{lineId:'5', isActive:true, length: '4'}},
   {id:'2',original:{lineId:'6', isActive:false, length: '7'}}
  ];
```

I tried to use .map() but I do something wrong.
Can You please suggest where is the issue ?

```
const newTab = tab.map(x => x.original.isActive === false ? 'off' : x.original.isActive === true ? 'on' : x);
```

This is how newTab should look like after change:

```
  const newTab = 
[
    {id:'0',original:{lineId:'4', isActive:'off', length: '3'}},
      {id:'1',original:{lineId:'5', isActive:'on', length: '4'}},
      {id:'2',original:{lineId:'6', isActive:'off', length: '7'}}
     ];
```

With current code it returns changed isActive property only:

```
const newTab = ["off", "on", "off"]
```

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return the entire object, not just `on` or `off` inside your map.  You can condense this using `...`(spread operator) and only modify `isActive` while returning everything else as is:

```js
const tab = [{
    id: '0',
    original: {
      lineId: '4',
      isActive: false,
      length: '3'
    }
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    original: {
      lineId: '5',
      isActive: true,
      length: '4'
    }
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    original: {
      lineId: '6',
      isActive: false,
      length: '7'
    }
  }
];

const newTab = tab.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  original: {
    ...item.original,
    isActive: item.original.isActive ? 'on' : 'off',
  }
}));

console.log(newTab)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread syntax, and you can update variables in map method.

```js
tab.map((e) => (
    {
        ...e,
        original: {
            ...e.original,
            isActive: e.original.isActive ? 'on' : 'off'
        }
    }
))
```

Comment: Don't post code only answers. Please try to let the OP know where they are wrong and how your code is correcting it.

Comment: thanks @TusharShahi i am updating.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a mapping and return a JSON by copying the values.

```js
const tab = [
    { id: '0', original: { lineId: '4', isActive: false, length: '3' } },
    { id: '1', original: { lineId: '5', isActive: true, length: '4' } },
    { id: '2', original: { lineId: '6', isActive: false, length: '7' } }
];

const tab2 = tab.map(e => {
        return {
            id: e.id,
            original: {
                lineId: e.original.lineId,
                isActive: e.original.isActive ? 'on' : 'off',
                length: e.original.length
            }
        }
    });
```

Output :
[Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQLyN.png)